# How to get Dynatree's parent node details

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

Is there any way to find dynatree's root node details? Supposed tree has 5 level and i selected fifth level's node . I want to get selected nodes and its parents details till root.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The **visitParents** function on the node should do what you want:

```
node.visitParents(function (node) { 
    // do stuff with node
}, true);
```

Passing true as the second parameter includes the node as well as it's parents.

Answer (score 2):

Try below method:

**`node.getKeyPath()`**

It should return string of keys from leaf to root node like below

**/_3/_23/_26/_27**

You should be then able to retrieve the any node details of that branch by parsing above string

**`var node = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").getNodeByKey("3")`**

This might not be the exact solution but should give you the direction to get to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = node.getParent();
var parentnode = parent.data.key;
```

In parentnode you will get the value of parent node.